# Flutter GridView images zoom in zoom out

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I am new to the flutter and i want to try make a responsive gridview to show images.

For example:

This is the initial state:

[image]

After changing the bar I want to make the screen look like this:

[image]

My main problem is i don't know how to implement this zoom in zoom out bar:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a scrollable grid, you should use `GridView`.

GridView needs a delegate that tells it how to layout its children. In this case, you probably want to use the `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount`. Notice it has a `crossAxisCount`, which represents the number of items in a row.

```
GridView(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 4, // <<<< Here
        childAspectRatio: 0.5,
      ),
      children: List<Widget>.generate(20, (int i) {
        return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Text('$i');
        });
      }),
    );
```

Then you can update the `crossAxisCount` when the slider changes, and your `GridView` will update.

Comment: Hi,thank you for the response. I'm sorry if I asked my question incomprehensible.My main problem is i don't know how to implement the slider.

Comment: You can use the [Slider class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html).

You can change the values of `min`, `max`, and `divisions` to limit the zoom the user can use.